# Is it a good practice to do full text search for all kinds of fields?

Tags: mysql, search

I am creating a search functionality for my website and I've learned that MySQL has full-text capability as of version 5.3.

I did some research and some people claim that full-text search is slower than LIKE search (which makes sense to me). I was doing LIKE search and the results are not awesome. However, with the full-text search I got much better results.

For the columns which has a lot of text, lets say, *content* which has more than 5K words. It makes sense to do full-text search. However, does it make sense to do full text search for the columns, lets say `first_name`, `last_name` which does not have much text.?

When I do LIKE search on those columns (first_name, last_name), I am searching every single text in all columns. Lets say, the search query is "ma meq". When I search, I use search "ma" in both *first_name* and *last_name* and same for the meq. The thing is releavance is much better in full text search.

I've created such a query:

```
select member_id FROM Members WHERE MATCH(Members.value) AGAINST ( 'ma meq*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND FIELD_ID IN(3,4)
```

This query gives me better results than like equivalent:

```
 select member_id FROM Members WHERE (value LIKE ma) AND field_id = 3
 select member_id FROM Members WHERE (value LIKE meq) AND field_id = 3
 select member_id FROM Members WHERE (value LIKE ma) AND field_id = 4
 select member_id FROM Members WHERE (value LIKE meq) AND field_id = 4
```

. What I am want to know is that is that a good practice? Does it make sense to use full-text search even if the column does not much text?

Answer (score 0):

Everything has use, but also have a cost. A full text search index is bigger. But not sure where you hear is slower. Is design to work with great volumen of data.

At the end you have to test and decide if the cost is worth the perfomance improvement.